# Nest sum,datediff and case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I have a table like this,

[image]

```
SELECT rd_rfiledelayid_pk, 
       rd_rfileid_fk_ind, 
       rd_enddate 
FROM   t_rfiledelay 
WHERE  rd_rfileid_fk_ind = '4873'
```

1. i need to get result as **date different summery** group by foreign key (`RD_RfileID_fk_ind`) and criteria is when `NULL` RD_EndDate get today date.

as this i tried like this,

```
SELECT rd_rfileid_fk_ind, 
       Sum(Datediff(day, rd_startdate, CASE 
                                         WHEN rd_enddate = NULL THEN Getdate() 
                                         ELSE rd_enddate 
                                       END)) AS ES_SubmittorDelays 
FROM   t_rfiledelay 
WHERE  rd_rfileid_fk_ind = '4873' 
GROUP  BY rd_rfileid_fk_ind
```

i got result,

[image]

but result need to like this,

> 2016-06-20 to 2016-06-25 = 5 days
>
> 2016-07-01 to today (2016-07-07) = 6 days
>
> and result need to be 11 days.

Can you please let me know what i miss here ?

Comment: `CASE 
when RD_EndDate=null..` should be `CASE 
when RD_EndDate Is null..`

Comment: Simply you can use `COALESCE` or `ISNULL` function

Comment: OMG i'm such a fool thank you @Prdp

Comment: Case expression, not statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query that you want:

```
SELECT RD_RfileID_fk_ind,
       SUM(DATEDIFF(day, RD_Startdate, COALESCE(RD_EndDate, GETDATE() ))
          ) as ES_SubmittorDelays
FROM t_RfileDelay 
WHERE RD_RfileID_fk_ind = '4873'
GROUP BY RD_RfileID_fk_ind;
```

Your problem is the `= NULL`.  The correct syntax is `IS NULL`; `=` never returns true when either (or both) of the arguments is `NULL`.

In any case, `COALESCE()` is simpler than `CASE`.